# What is the difference between spring factory-method and factory-bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-social, springsource

I am new Springs. In Bean tag I found factory-method and factory-bean Attributes. What is the difference between factory-method and factory-bean?

I am using factory-method to call my getInstance static method to create singleton object.

What is factory-bean used for?

---

For given replies, What I understood was

Factory-method is used for calling a static method to create object in same bean class.

Factory-bean is used for creating a object based on factory design pattern.

Ex:- I am asking a EggPlant object from VegetableFactory (Which will return vegetable object which was asked)class by passing my vegetable name(EggPlant in this case).

Please correct if I am wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's basically the same difference between the *Factory method* and *Factory* design patterns, with a little note at the bottom. While one is a method used to obtain instances of a specific class, the other is a full fledged object responsible of creating objects, including all of the required logic to do so.

`FactoryBean`'s interface documentation states:

> Interface to be implemented by objects used within a BeanFactory which are themselves factories. If a bean implements this interface, it is used as a factory for an object to expose, not directly as a bean instance that will be exposed itself.

Also, this object **is not used as a bean instance**, but as an instance provider through its `getObject` method.

---

#### Update

Searching for uses of `factory-method` over a `FactoryBean`, it seems that it used quite oftenly with legacy singleton beans, to get the underlying instance, but this approach doesn't provide support for initialization methods, such as, for example, an `init` method that initializes a given set of properties.

In this case, you either have to invoke it yourself before using the class, define a wrapper that handles the initialization or make use of other mechanisms such as `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`.

---

#### Update 2

Strictly speaking, a `FactoryBean` is intended to manage a specific type. You'd have, in fact, an `EggPlantFactory`, not a `VegetableFactory` since the `getObject` method defined by the `FactoryBean` interface doesn't support parameters.

Answer (score 26):

```
factory-method: represents the factory method that will be invoked to inject the bean.
factory-bean: represents the reference of the bean by which factory method will be invoked. It is used if factory method is non-static.
```

Printable.java

```
package com.javatpoint;  
public interface Printable {  
    void print();  
}
```

A.java

```
package com.javatpoint;  
public class A implements Printable{  
    @Override  
    public void print() {  
        System.out.println("hello a");  
    }      
}
```

B.java

```
package com.javatpoint;  
public class B implements Printable{  
    @Override  
    public void print() {  
        System.out.println("hello b");  
    }  
}
```

PrintableFactory.java

```
package com.javatpoint;  
public class PrintableFactory {  
    //non-static factory method  
    public Printable getPrintable(){  
        return new A();//return any one instance, either A or B  
    }  
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="pfactory" class="com.javatpoint.PrintableFactory"></bean>  
<bean id="p" class="com.javatpoint.Printable" factory-method="getPrintable"   
factory-bean="pfactory"></bean>  

</beans>
```

Notice that `public Printable getPrintable()` of `PrintableFactory.java` is a **non-static method**. Generally if we want access/call method or other resources of the a class we have to create it's instance. Similarly in that we created it bean. using bean's reference variable `pfactory` we are calling the factory method `getPrintable`.

Answer (score 10):

**factory-method:**
As everyone has already explained, **factory-method** is used to tell the spring to use the factory method to instantiate the object.

Note: static method is mandatory else throws an exception.

```
<bean id="serviceFactory" class="com.test.controller.ServiceFactory" factory-method="getServiceFacrotyWithStaticMethod"/>
```

**factory-bean:**
When there is no static method and still you want to create the object using non static method, here is the trick can be done using **factory-bean**:

```
<bean id="instanceWithOutStaticMethod" factory-bean="serviceFactory" factory-method="getInstanceWithOutStaticMethod" />
```

Note: no class attribute required in the above spring definition.

**Class:**

```
public class ServiceFactory {

    public static ServiceFactory getServiceFacrotyWithStaticMethod(){
        return new ServiceFactory();
    }

    public SdCard getInstanceWithOutStaticMethod(){
        return new AdaptorSlot("laptop");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find [documentation about this here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.4/reference/beans.html). See section 3.2.3.2 and 3.2.3.3.

`factory-method` is used to point to a static method in legacy code that can be used to create a bean.

> Quite similar to using a static factory method to create a bean, is the use of an instance (non-static) factory method, where a factory method of an existing bean from the factory is called to create the new bean.

This is what `factory-bean` is for.

Answer (score 2):

A [FactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) is used as factory for other beans/objects. It cannot be used as bean itself.

The `factory-method` can be used to define the method that should be used to create this bean (instead of calling the constructor). A bean with a factory method can be used as a bean itself.

Spring can create bean instances using many different factory types. This is useful if you want to integrate libraries/legacy classes that are bound to a particular type.

Answer (score 1):

in spring we use  factory-method because in java predefine class and some use define class are there the are not provide direct to create the object of other class there are some abstract class we can not create object but in side the class there are method are there like `Calendar` class we can not create the object of `Calendar` class

```
Calendar cal = new Calendar();
```

it is wrong on that thime its give error but it is provide the method `getInstance()` we can call the method and we can instance the class

Example:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
```

it is correct on that time we use factory method in the spring example:

```
<bean id="cal" class="Calendar" factory-method="getInstance">
```