# What's the reason to instantiate Spring beans with factory methods?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, static-factory

I know there are constructor-based injection and setter-based injection in Spring. When should I use factory methods to inject beans?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between spring factory-method and factory-bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772490/what-is-the-difference-between-spring-factory-method-and-factory-bean)

Answer (score 3):

It's rather a design matter and depends on your architecture.

If you have classes with static factory methods, why should you add unnecessary constructors breaking the design just to fit a DI framework?

It's inflexible, thus Spring supports both ways.

---

Excerpt from [**Joshua Bloch “Effective Java”**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997):

> ### Item 1: Consider static factory methods instead of constructors.
>
> **Static factory methods advantages:**
>
> - They have names.
> - They are not required to create a new object each time they are invoked.
> - They can return an object of any subtype of    their return type.
> - They reduce verbosity of creating parameterized type instances.
>
> **Static factory methods disadvantages:**
>
> - When providing only static factory methods, classes without public or protected constructors cannot be subclassed.
> - They are not readily distinguishable from other static methods

Comment: Should this factory method usually produce prototype or singleton beans?

Comment: @Diamond, I believe we can produce an any-scoped bean in this way

Comment: @Diamond, All the scopes have the stage where a bean is initialised at. You specify only the way it's going to be constructed. No much difference between a constructor and a static method here. Is that helpful?